# Is checking the existence of an objects key considered timing safe?

Tags: javascript, cryptojs, timing-attack

So, I'm authing a pretty short list of users for a mostly private server, and the login data for these users in stored in an object. The object is structured like {"username":"hash"}. I'd like to know if using something like `if(users[username) {timingSafeCompare(hash,users[username])}` is considered timing safe.

I thought of using something like

```
let u = false
for(un in users) {
    if(timingSafeCompare(username,un) && timingSafeCompare(hash,users[un])) u = username
}
return u
```

But again, I'm not sure if that's timing safe.

What would be the best approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on engine's implementation.

Some engines use hash-tables to store properties and use dynamic lookup, hash tables have O(n) worst case time complexity.

[V8 tries to improve it by using hidden classes](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties), and brings down time complexity to O(1) for best case. However as number of props grows it falls back to dynamic lookup.

For [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) V8 [uses ordered hash table](https://codereview.chromium.org/220293002/) which also has O(1) time complexity.

If you are also going to delete `users` as well then `Set` or `Map` can outperform object. Using `Set` also makes it more semantically correct.

Comment: Much appreciated! The project is in nodejs so ya V8. Do you know what the threshold is for an object's prop, like the amount of props it can hold before V8 falls back to dynamic lookup? Just curious, as I'll be using Set per your suggestion